# WPF DataGridHyperlinkColumn is not firing Click event

Tags: c#, wpf

The project based on WPF.
I have just created simple datagid in the window. There are a view columns and one of them is DataGridHyperlinkColumn which should work as a button.

Below you can see the datagrid code.

```html
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dgdBets" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="293" Margin="10,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <DataGrid.DataContext>
                            <Common:Bet/>
                        </DataGrid.DataContext>
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id">
                                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" >
                                        <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler"></EventSetter>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                            </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="120" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Название" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="190" Binding="{Binding Path=Description}" Header="Описание" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="120" Binding="{Binding Path=BetTypeName}" Header="Тип" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Of course I created method EventSetter_OnHandler in C# side but it's not working.

Who knows what's wrong here?

Comment: You code works, nothing wrong in it. Can u run you app in debug mode, check to see errors reported in the output window?

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'System.Int32' and 'System.Uri'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=Id; DataItem='Bet' (HashCode=49136085); target element is 'Hyperlink' (HashCode=59836530); target property is 'NavigateUri' (type 'Uri')

Comment: well, you can ignore them as you are setting eventhandler for it. What is happening when you click on Id column? Does the event handler not fired?

Comment: @MikeTkachev: You should change the type of your `Id` property to `System.Uri` from `System.Int32` (`int`) for the binding error to go away. Or what is your exact issue here?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just wanted to use it as a button. So this option is already removed and now I use click event for the row. @RajN thank you very much again.